# Measure algebra for a family of probability measures

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $(X,B,P)$ be a probability space, $I_P$ the $\sigma$-ideal of $P$-null sets and
\begin{align}
B_P = B \ltimes I_P &= \{ A \mathbin{\triangle} N \mid A \in B, N \in I_P \}
\end{align}
the completion of the $\sigma$-algebra $B$ w.r.t. $P$.
One can then define its *measure algebra* by the quotient:
\begin{align}
M_P&:= B_P/I_P,
\end{align}
together with its descent of $P$ onto $M_P$.

In a certain sense, the measure algebra captures all relevant structure of $(X,B,P)$ and is often more 'natural' to work with than $(X,B,P)$ as it automatically identifies everything up to $P$-null sets, etc.

However, in statistics one often encounters spaces with a family of probability measures, e.g. consider statistical models, transition probabilities or hypothesis testing, etc.

So we now want to consider a measurable space $(X,B)$ equipped with a set/family $S$ of probability measures $P$ on $(X,B)$. This could be for example $(\mathbb{R},B_\mathbb{R})$, the set of real numbers together with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $S$ the set of all probability measures on $(\mathbb{R},B_\mathbb{R})$.

We can now define the *$S$-completion* of $B$ as the intersection of all $P$-completions, $P \in S$:
\begin{align}
B_S &:= \bigcap_{P \in S} B_P.
\end{align}

In the mentioned example this would be then the $\sigma$-algebra of all *universally measurable* subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

The (rather vague) question now is, if there exists a well-behaved notion of *measure algebra* for $B_S$ w.r.t. $S$ that allows for a similar theory as before, e.g. with corresponding constructions of Stone spaces and Gelfand spectrum, etc.? If so, references would be appreciated.

Note that in general we *cannot* write:
\begin{align}
B_S &= B \ltimes I_S
\end{align}
with some $\sigma$-ideal $I_S$ anymore.